# Probability between two events following exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Two independent events A and B follow exponential distribution with parameter L:
f(t)=L*e^(-L*t) for t>=0. If X is the time where A occurs and Y the time where B occurs, calculate the probability P[X>=2*Y] meaning that A happens at least after double the time that B occurred.

How do I proceed?
I need to integrate f(t) in the area where x>=2*y. Does that mean that 0<=y<=x/2?

Comment: Random variables can follow exponential distribution but not events.

Comment: Correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ to be random variables, you need to integrate the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ which is easy to compute as they are independent. Your integral limits are fine: $0\leq x<\infty, 0\leq y\leq x/2$. I think the final answer is $1/3$.

Comment: Indeed, although using $0\leq y\leq \infty, 2y\leq x\leq \infty$ might be slightly easier to handle.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you.